# Plotting of piecewise functions from file

Tags: tikz-pgf

I use `tikz` package for graph plotting. I have piecewise function [image]
,

which set as array of values in text file.

How I can plot given function this way?

Comment: Use pgffplots table input.  If smoothing, put blank lines at the transitions, and possibly double up the inflection points (t=0.35 and t=0.55)

Comment: you can plot 3 times with 3 different domains

Answer (score 1):

Of course you can declare such a function and plot it with plain Ti*k*Z. (I do agree with John Kormylo that `pgfplots` may be more appropriate, but there you can just plot the function, there is no need for tables.) With `samples at` you can control the points where the function is evaluated. In the domains in which the function is linear, there is no need to have more than 2 samples.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[declare function={f(\x)=ifthenelse(\x<0.35,-\x,
ifthenelse(\x<0.55,(2-\x)*\x,-\x));}]
 \draw[-stealth] (0,0) -- (1.2,0) node[below left]{$t$};
 \draw[-stealth] (0,-1) -- (0,1) node[below left]{$f(t)$};
 \draw[blue] plot[variable=\x,domain=0:1,samples
 at={0,0.3499,0.35,0.36,0.37,...,0.55,0.55001,1}] ({\x},{f(\x)});
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]